# Query Elasticsearch for return only 1 data in Elasticsearch Head Extention

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query

My data in user.created_at field is like below

```
Tue Mar 10 23:03:00 +0000 2020
Tue Mar 10 04:29:18 +0000 2020
Tue Jan 21 08:45:43 +0000 2020
Tue Mar 10 00:11:45 +0000 2020
Tue Jan 28 04:11:45 +0000 2020
Sun Mar 08 10:19:19 +0000 2020
```

And I tried to Query ES like:

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
        "match": {
          "sentiment": "neutral"
         }
        }
        ,
       {
        "wildcard": {
          "user.created_at": "*2020"
         }
       }
       ,
       {
        "match": {
          "user.created_at": "Tue Mar 10"
         }
       }
      ],
      "must_not": [ ],
      "should": [ ]
       }
    }}
```

But there is also show another datas which is that I don't want too.
The result keep showing other date. Like below

[Keep Showing other date, not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzTOl.png)

My Question is, how do I return only one data with date **Tue Mar 10 23:03:00 +0000 2020** specifically ? Is there any way to get only 1 hits data with that specific date. I don't have any idea about this. Please help me.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the response you get for the shown query?

Comment: Add a timestamp parser in logstash, and then there's the datetime type

Comment: I don't use Logstash

Answer (score 1):

What's your `created_at`'s mapping type? When it's a `date`, you can use a `range` query with the correct date [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html):

```
...
"query": {
    "range": {
      "user.created_at": {
        "gte": "2020-03-10",
        "lt": "2020-03-11"
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: I don't know about mapping, so I think it is only default type. How to mapping in ES? Sorry, I'm newbie about ES. Is there any way to mapping field while there is not an empty field?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem. I am using a long Query to get the specific hits with long date value in a field.

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": [
    {
     "match": {
      "sentiment": "neutral"
     }
    }
    ,
   {
    "wildcard": {
     "user.created_at": "*2020"
    }
   }
   ,
  {
   "match": {
    "user.created_at": "Tue"
   }
  }
  ,
  {
   "match": {
    "user.created_at": "Mar"
   }
  }
  ,
  {
   "match": {
    "user.created_at": "10"
    }
   }
   ,
   {
    "match": {
     "user.created_at": "Tue Mar"
    }
   }
   ,
   {
    "match": {
      "user.created_at": "Mar 10"
     }
   }
   ],
   "must_not": [ ],
   "should": [ ]
  }
 },
 "from": 0,
 "size": 250,
 "sort": [ ],
 "aggs": { }
}
```